# Merging from Git main branch to protected feature branch

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have long been anti-feature branch but my current team use them. I wasn't happy because of the enormous PR into main at the end could be used to hide un-reviewed code. We have required PR approvers but the general thought is that the last PR "must be OK because all the individual PRs are approved". The team wasn't squashing so the commit history was unruly anyway.

I have accepted as a compromise the use of protected feature branches. The thought being that then, because nothing can be merged directly, everything *has* to have been reviewed.

The problem now comes that I use [an auto update github action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/auto-update) to keep the PRs in sync. If master updates I want the feature to update and then the PR branches to update. It worked before the protection was applied to the Feature branch, but now **the protection rules prevent the merge commits from master**.

This must be a common pattern of work? How do I do it?

Comment: You could use a PAT for a bot user in that action, and then exempt that bot user from the branch protection rule.

Comment: Are `master` updates hotfixes that need to be merged down to the "protected feature branch"? If yes, how often are hotfixes occurring? Also, what is meant by the second half of this sentence: "If master updates I want the feature to update *and then the PR branches to update*." (Why do you also need the "PR branches to update"?)

Comment: @TTT perhaps ignore that part, I just mean that I need the tip of the main branch, the feature branch and the pr-to-feature branch to be in alignment after main updates

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks, I am looking into that now

Comment: @tallpaul Got it. I would say you probably only need the protected feature branch to get updated with `main`. Branches PR'ing into that protected feature branch typically wouldn't need them unless they were working on the same stuff, in which case there would be conflicts and they'd be forced to merge or rebase to update their branch. This is no different than if you didn't even have a separate `main` branch. Every time `main` updates with one PR, all existing branches with PR's into `main` wouldn't necessarily need to be updated, unless they have conflicts.

Comment: Anyway. I'd go with PAT suggestion. Let the bot bypass the protection rule. Then you only need to be involved with that merge when there are conflicts and the bot fails.